# Set tooltip using html text

Tags: c#, asp.net

need to set table cell tool tip from text like below.
table created dynamically.

```
<div>Red - if &gt; 1.5 % gross margin erosion</div>    <div>Yellow - if &gt;.5% - 1.49 % variance</div>
```

I need to remove html tags and show tool tip as below

```
Red - if > 1.5 % gross margin erosion
Yellow - if >.5% - 1.49 % variance
```

can you help me pls.

what i currently doing is

```
tooltiptext=   System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(tooltiptext);
```

and replcace DIV tags from string

after asign it to table cell tooltip value.

this is working but is there any way to format html text and replcace tags on it other than above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by setting the table cell to runat="server" and then  in code behind you can add the tooltip.

Also you can easily assign the condition in code behind.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="td1" run="server">sample text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And in code behind use this inside the condition

```
    ((HtmlTableCell)this.FindControl("td1")).Attributes.Add("Title", "test");
```

Comment: I think this question revolves more around the HTML encoding / decoding, since he already has the string in HTML encoded format.